# flip effect: flip div one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im working on a simple flip effect, its working fine actually, I just want to add another effect, which is it will flip one by one after I click the flip button.

I hope you understand me.

Thanks.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/JZPqLY)

```
     <div class="row numList flip-panel">
<div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num front">
  1
    </div>
    <div class="num back">
    2
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num front">
    2
</div>
    <div class="num back">
3
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num front">
  3
    </div>
    <div class="num back">
    4
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num front">
4   
</div>
    <div class="num back">
    5
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num front">
    5
</div>
    <div class="num back">
    6
</div>

    </div>
</div>
<button>flip</button>
```

Comment: try using `.each()` and try to put timer on it, I think it will flip one by one

Comment: What do you mean by one by one cannot understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your html, you apply `flip` effect to the outermost div which contains all the numbers. You need to apply the effect for each div separately. You need to add `flip-panel` class to each div you need to flip separately. Then you can use a `for` loop and `setTimeout` for apply the style sequentially.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var panel = $('.flip-panel');
    for (let i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        panel.eq(i).addClass('flip');
      }, 500 * i);
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
  .flip-panel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
}
.col-md-5ths{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */

/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */
.flip-panel .front {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.flip-panel.flip .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-panel .back {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.flip-panel.flip .back {
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row numList">
 <div class="col-md-5ths flip-panel">
  <div class="num front">
      1
  </div>
  <div class="num back">
  2
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5ths flip-panel">
  <div class="num front">
  2
    </div>
  <div class="num back">
    3
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5ths flip-panel">
  <div class="num front">
      3
  </div>
  <div class="num back">
  4
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5ths flip-panel">
  <div class="num front">
    4 
    </div>
  <div class="num back">
  5
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5ths flip-panel">
  <div class="num front">
  5
    </div>
  <div class="num back">
  6
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<button>flip</button>
```